# Cannot convert Object to Int c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to cast Object to Integer value.
When I run my project it shows "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

I don't know why this error happens.

Here my code.

```
int[] ShapeID = (int[])ShapeIDS;
int shapeindex = System.Convert.ToInt32(ShapeID);
```

Comment: An int-array is not an int, it possibly contains multiple ints.

Comment: you cant convert array to int.

Comment: But the variable 'ShapeID' shows the value '38' when i click on a point. Please tell me how to get the single value form list of array values

Comment: `ShapeID` is an array and you are trying to convert a collection into a single Int which is not feasible. `System.Convert.ToInt32(ShapeID[i]);`

Comment: Please show the type of `ShapeIDS`.

Answer (score 4):

The compile-time error expresses that `int[]` does not implement `IConvertible`. I believe that in fact you would like to cast every element or a certain element of `ShapeIDS` to `IConvertible` like in the following lines.

```
int[] ShapeID = (int[])ShapeIDS;
int shapeindex =ShapeID[0];
```